# Indian citizen: do I need a Croatia/Bosnia/Montenegro visa if I have a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, croatia, montenegro, bosnia

My upcoming travel plans include applying for a multi entry Schengen visa to visit Europe (France, Italy, Hungary and Belgium). However in between this trip, I also plan to visit Croatia, Bosnia and Herzegovina and Montenegro. As per the visa rules for these 3 countries that I read online, I found that merely possessing a multiple entry Schengen visa (with an active entry remaining) for these 3 countries is enough for being eligible to get a visa on arrival for these 3 countries.

However, having recently gone through this article (http://indiancompass.com/2011/02/schengen-visa-why-it-matters-when-travelling-via-eurorailinterrail/)  which gives the example of Serbia (having the same rules as the other 3 countries of visa on arrival for multi entry Schengen holders), I am in doubt.

It would be great if someone could confirm that my plan is okay and I can enter Croatia, Bosnia and Montenegro on a multiple entry Schengen visa.

Comment: The article you linked to is five years old (2011). Have you found anything that is sync'd up to the current rules?

Comment: Yes all the other sources (as well as a few stackexchange questions) point to my trip planning being correct. But I just thought it will be good to confirm if the rules are the same for an Indian citizen with my itinerary.

Comment: Serbia recognizes the Schengen multiply visas since 2014. The article you linked is too old.

Comment: Note that the itinerary you describe does not require a multiple-entry visa and there are no reason for any Schengen consulate to issue one for this. **They don't have to do it merely to help you go to completely unrelated countries like Serbia,** it's only a side-effect of the visa, not a consideration that would be legally relevant for the Schengen visa process.

Comment: @Relaxed nice one!

Comment: @Relaxed I took "in between this trip" to mean that the itinerary calls for visits to the non-Schengen countries and then a return to (at least one of) the Schengen countries.  Such an itinerary *would* call for at least a dual-entry Schengen visa.

Comment: @phoog I hadn't noticed that but two-entry visas were indeed specifically intended for this kind of things and especially for side trips to the UK. As far as Schengen regulations are concerned they are closer to single-entry than to multiple-entry visas but I don't know about the rules in Montenegro or Bosnia & Herzegovina.

Comment: @Relaxed the Croatia quote in the current answer does say "two or multiple."

Comment: @Relaxed "Note that the itinerary you describe does not require a multiple-entry visa" - So what should I do to show the visa consulate the need of a multiple entry visa ? My trip goes like this : Italy - Hungary - Croatia - B/H - Montenegro - Belgium - France. Is this good to justify a multi entry visa ?

Comment: @YashDesai The thing is that multiple-entry visas are intended for trusted travellers who have already been to the Schengen area many times and need to travel regularly to a specific country (e.g. for business reasons). You can always request one and be lucky but there isn't really any sure-fire way to get one for what is essentially a single trip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Bosnia & Herzegovina**](http://www.bhembassy.no/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=17&Itemid=28&lang=en)

> Foreigners who have multiple Schengen visa or European Union member state visa or residence permit of the Schengen Agreement country or European Union member state, if for such passport holders visa is required, can stay up to 15 days in Bosnia and Herzegovina without visa under condition that they enter in BiH from the Schengen Agreement country, European Union member state or from the country with which BiH has an agreement on readmission in force - Macedonia, Montenegro, Serbia.

[**Montenegro**](http://www.mvpei.gov.me/en/sections/consular-affairs/visa-regimes-for-foreign-citizens/)

> Holders of travel documents containing a valid Schengen visa, a valid visa of the United States of America, United Kingdom and Northern Ireland and the Republic of Ireland, or a permission to stay in these countries, may enter and stay, or pass through the territory of Montenegro up to 30 days, and not longer than the expiry of visa, if the period of validity of the visa is less than 30 days.

[**Croatia**](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/)

> Aliens who are holders of uniform visa (C) for two or multiple entries, valid for all Schengen Area Member States

Additional [information regarding Croatia](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/croatia-could-join-schengen-area-after-2018/).

Comment: Membership in the EU does not by itself imply that a country will accept Schengen visas.  The UK and Ireland are notable examples.

Comment: This is bad. And weird. For Montenegro > "if the period of validity of the visa is less than 30 days.". The duration of the schengen visa you mean ? The entire length of my trip from start to end would require a schengen visa with a validity of 34 days. So then I would not be eligible for entering Montenegro ?

Comment: I only need to spend 3 days in Montenegro. My days in schengen zone would be 22. Rest days would be Croatia, B/H and Montenegro. So then I would not be eligible for entering Montenegro ?

Comment: Correct phoog, I should only cite official documents, not my own opinions, thanks :)

Comment: I have an India passport with a valid 1 year multiple entry Schengen visa. I recently travelled to all of these countries, landing in Croatia and then travelling by road from Croatia to BiH and then to Montenegro and then back into Croatia. All countries have visa-free access with multiple entry Schengen visa. There was no issue at land borders or airports.